React-Navigation: Browser Native Navigation Causing Broken Navigation on Redirected Screens - How to Resolve?
I have React-Native application (Expo) and I am using react-navigation for both Mobile and Web parts. I need to add url integration on Web and generally with some nuances react-navigation allows to do it.
I have some screens that user should not be able to access with url (only by navigating through the app). So I decided to implement redirection function as I didn't find ready solution for that and I got:
const linking = useMemo<LinkingOptions<ReactNavigation.RootParamList>>(
    () => ({
      prefixes,
      config: {
        screens: {
          TabsNavigator: tabsScreens,
          LoginNavigator: loginScreens,
        },
      },
      getPathFromState(state, config) {
        ... // Here I just make params not be shown in path
      },
      getStateFromPath(path, config) {
        const state = getStateFromPath(path, config);

        const loginRedirectionPaths = [
          'reset_password_success',
          'consent',
          'terms',
        ];

        const shouldRedirectToLogin = loginRedirectionPaths.some(
          pathSubstring => path.includes(pathSubstring),
        );

        const therapyRedirectionPaths = [
          'knowledge',
          'steps',
          'today-overview',
          'week-overview',
          'exercise',
          'messages',
        ];

        const shouldRedirectToTherapy = therapyRedirectionPaths.some(
          pathSubstring => path.includes(pathSubstring),
        );

        const redirect = (
          routeName: 'Login' | 'TherapyNavigator',
          screenPath: 'sign_in' | 'therapy',
        ) => ({
          ...state,
          routes: [{name: routeName, params: {screen: screenPath}}],
        });

        if (shouldRedirectToLogin) {
          return redirect('Login', 'sign_in');
        }

        if (shouldRedirectToTherapy) {
          return redirect('TherapyNavigator', 'therapy');
        }

        return state;
      },
    }),
    [loginScreens, prefixes, tabsScreens],

Here I have getStateFromPath that redirects user during first entering and linking is passing to NavigationContainer.
But, when user starts using native browser navigation buttons, user can access redirected screen: title is from redirected screen and in state it's kinda on redirected screen, but other things like path and content are okay.
Any suggestions?
